# query that groups cell data based on attribute

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

What would I need to look into form making a query on a table that looks like this:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | x | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | x | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | x | 4 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | y | 5 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | y | 6 |
+---+---+---+

Into results that looks like this:

+---+---+-------+
| A | B | C     |
+---+---+-------+
| 1 | x | 2 3 4 |
+---+---+-------+
| 2 | y | 5 6   |
+---+---+-------+
```

The rows that have similar values from attribute A are grouped into one column though the different values from C are merged together.

Please let me know if you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT A, B, C = 
(SELECT ' ' + C
       FROM #yt b 
       WHERE b.A = a.A and b.B = a.B 
      FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM #yt a
GROUP BY A, B
```

I used this:

```
CREATE TABLE #yt
    ([A] int, [B] varchar(25), [C] int)
;

INSERT INTO #yt
    ([A], [B], [C])
VALUES
    (1, 'x', 2),
    (1, 'x', 3),
    (1, 'x', 4),
    (2, 'y', 5),
    (2, 'y', 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention about what database you are using but for PostgreSQL you can use `array_agg` function with `group by` like below:

```
SELECT "A", "B", array_agg("C") AS C
FROM Table1
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Check solution for PostgreSQL in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d54c45/4)

Or for mysql you can use `group_concat` like below:

```
SELECT A, B, group_concat(C) AS C
FROM Table1
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Check solution for MySQL in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dd6a0/2)

Hope it helps.

Comment: `string_agg()` is the better choice for Postgres